# Adding custom Text in right part of toolbar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) component and I have found it very interesting to manage events. I want to add some custom message in the right corner of header to the user. I tried the following

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
           header:{
              left: 'prev,next,today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'Manage your events'
           }

    });
})
```

But it does not show in the right corner of the header. I have been able to render custom text  like following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#calendar').fullcalendar({
           header:{
              left: 'prev,next,today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'title'
           },
           titleFormat: '[Manage your events]'


    });
});
```

But by doing this, calendar component start showing same text in middle and right corner of the toolbar. What I want is to show custom text in right corner and show default title (which is month + year) in the center part of the toolbar. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[image]As I understand it the header option can only display specific calendar elements, not custom text. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/header/.

"But by doing this, calendar component start showing same text in middle and right corner of the toolbar." - of course it does - you have 'title' in center and right. It is doing what the docs say it will do. ...

titleFormat appears to be expecting a format string not text. Again; this is as per the docs: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/ .... It isn't intended for the purpose you are trying to use it for.

It may well be that it isn't designed to show custom text in the header bar. Looking at the demo http://fullcalendar.io/ that is how it looks. In which case you could show nothing in the right (just don't use right in header) and then do some custom css. (maybe target the element and try to add your custom text with :content?)

Update. I went to the demo http://fullcalendar.io/ and poked about with the element inspector in Chrome. I found the css for the right hand element and added this:

```
.fc-toolbar .fc-right:before {
    float: right;
    content: 'My Custom Text';
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: yep, it works but it does not put the content in h2 element as it otherwise would if it is set through title

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what you mean by 'set through title'? What option in the docs are you referring too? And the h2 is in the middle around 'May 2016' and you said you wanted the CustomText at the right. Which is what I gave you. If you want the custom text to be in an h2 then it looks like you'll have to extend the plugin.

Comment: forget the docs. lets say my title is showing in h2 if I put it the `fc-right` portion of the toolbar. I want my custom text to match the formatting of the title

Comment: even in your screenshot, you can see that the format of `My custom text` is different from the title shown in the center

Comment: Ok. Fine. This wasn't clear to me from your original post. Actually I am not quite sure about 'extending a jQuery plugin'. A quick hack would be just to hack it with jQuery? Something like: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    }).find('fc_toolbar .fc-right').html('<h2>My Custom text in an h2</h2>')?

Comment: yes, it works fine when calendar renders for first time. But when I press next or prev button, it starts showing the title in right corner as well as opposed to `My Custom Text`

Comment: I think, there has to be a render callback in the docs. let me check that one

Comment: eventRender maybe? Or -  is it showing the title because that is still part of your original header options? Just take out the 'right' bit in header?

Comment: even if I take out right from header options the result is still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111013/discussion-between-muhammad-adeel-zahid-and-justin-wyllie).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar today, but in my case I just wanted to insert custom text in the center element of the toolbar. After looking at the CSS for the header toolbar, I came up with this to put my text into the center of the toolbar (this is on version 5.3.0 of fullcalendar-scheduler, no idea if the CSS is the same on other versions):

```
.fc-header-toolbar > .fc-toolbar-chunk:nth-child(2)::before {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  content: 'My Custom Header Text';
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In FullCalendar V5, you can try this:

```
viewClassNames: function(view) {
    $('.fc-dayGridMonth-button').before("\
        <div class='label' style='line-height: 30px;margin-top:5px'>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#0aa858;font-size:14px'>&nbspAA&nbsp</i>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#ffbc32;font-size:14px'>&nbspBB&nbsp</i>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#f4433c;font-size:14px'>&nbspCC&nbsp</i>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#a5a5a5;font-size:14px'>&nbspDD&nbsp</i>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#5B9BD5;font-size:14px'title='EEEE'>&nbspEE&nbsp</i>\
        <i class='fa fa-square' style='color:#ED7D31;font-size:14px'title='FFFF'>&nbspFF&nbsp</i>\
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</i>\
        </div>\
    ");
},
```

In FullCalendar V3:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
  // $('.fc-month-button').before("\
},
```

So view looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f35M.jpg)